# recursive code for sorting a vector in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

In the recursive function (sort) The last element is poped back and stored in the variable and then the recursive function sorts the rest of the vector and in the induction step of the function, the element which was poped back is put into the right position via while loop in the new vector res.
But there happens to be a segmentation fault in the code Can somebody help me with this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

void sort(vector <int> &v){
    vector<int> res;
    if(v.size()==1){
        return ;
    }
      int temp= v[v.size()-1];
      v.pop_back();
      sort(v);
      
      int it=0;
      while(it<=v.size()){
         
        if(temp<v[it]){
            res.insert(it+v.begin(), temp);
            temp=1000000;
        }
        else{
            res.push_back(v[it]);
            it=it+1;
        }
      }
      cout<<res.size();
      return ;
}

int main(){
   
        vector <int> v;
        v.push_back(4);
        v.push_back(0);
        v.push_back(7);
        v.push_back(9);
        sort(v);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you simulate this very small example with pen and paper?

Comment: This `it <= v.size()` will be a problem. Vector indexes are zero-based, if a vector has `N` elements the valid indexes are `0..N-1`. You probably want `it < v.size()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few number of problems in your code. The most apparent is in the res vector inset line. You wish to insert the temp value at it + res.begin() , not at it + v.begin() (I assume you want to insert the value in res, so the position parameter where temp has to be inserted must be of res and not v).

Also what if the values before temp in v are already sorted. You need a condition to check that too.

Also, keep in mind 'it' cannot be equal to v.size() in the while loop condition.

Finally, you are passing v as a reference and popping it's last element out in each recursive call so the while loop part will always work with a v of size 1 (no matter at what point of operation you are). So, you have to update v at the end. I hope you just forgot to include the statement " v = res " at the end.

Also, no need to return at the end . The function is void type.
Rest is alright!

Here's the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;


void sort(vector <int> & v){
    vector<int> res;
    if(v.size()==1)
    {
        return ;
    }
      int temp= v[v.size()-1];
      v.pop_back();
      sort(v);
      
      int it=0;
      while(it<v.size())
      {
         
        if(temp<v[it])
        {
            res.insert(it+res.begin(), temp);
            temp=1000000;
        }
        else
        {
            res.push_back(v[it]);
            it=it+1;
        }
      }
      
      // If the values before temp are already in sorted order
      if(res.size()==v.size())
      res.push_back(temp);
      
      v=res;
}

int main()
{
   
    vector <int> v;
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(9);
    sort(v);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    return 0; 
}
```